# MySQL: How to get more results with this query WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql, where-in

My table for the categories

```
  table concept_category:
  id   category_title
 -----------------------------
  1     category1_title    
  2     category2_title    
  3     category3_title    
  4     category4_title    
  5     category5_title
```

and the table with the concepts

```
  table concept:
  id   catid  title
 -----------------------------
  1     3,5    title concept1
  2     5      title concept2
  3     2      title_concept3
```

Now I try to get all the results where the catid is 5. But the result it is giving is only the title_concept 2 and I want both title_concept1 and title_concept2. This is my query

```
SELECT id, title, catid                                             
FROM concept 
WHERE catid = (5)
```

Im not seeing what im doing wrong.. can somebody help me?

Comment: 1. Normalize your data.

Comment: I like juergen's answer below, but ideally you would want to store the association between the 2 tables in a 3rd table. You have a many-to-many relationship, which calls for 3 tables. 1 for categories, 1 for concepts, and 1 for the relationship between the 2 - something like "categories_to_concepts".

Comment: Why to many associations? Its just a "concept" that can by placed in more then one category

Answer (score 4):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT id, title, catid                                       
FROM concept
where find_in_set(5, replace(catid, ' ', '')) > 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6b97/2)

Comment: Thanks juergen, but I still get one result when I use you're suggestion

Comment: Is it possible to use this when i have spaces in the set? Now it only works with a set like this: 1,2,3,4,5 but i want it to work when i have a set with spaces like this: 1, 2, 3, 4 ?

Comment: I updated my answer. But the problems you face are because of bad DB design. Don't ever store multiple values in one column. You see now that this is asking for trouble. If you have a chance then change the table structure.

Comment: Thanks juergen!! I can't change it because im using a class for storingt these category's (www.formhandler.net) dbListField.. and it stores the values like this..